# "Hidden layer sizes" vs "Hidden layers sizes"

Tags: nouns, grammatical-number, possessives

I am writing a neural network application. In this application, a neural network can have one or more hidden layers, which can have different sizes (neuron counts).

Which label would be correct: "hidden layer sizes" or "hidden layers sizes" and why? I realize this is a more general grammar related question and I'd love to learn about it.

EDIT:
the label is for a text box, where user will enter numbers separated by commas.

Comment: It's shoe stores, book shelves, student lists, lesson counts, beer bottles, layer sizes.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your phrase, *hidden layer* is an attributive noun: it's a noun which behaves as an adjective modifying *sizes*.

In English, adjectives are not inflected for number; that is, the form of an adjective doesn't change depending on the number of what it's describing. [This differs from French, for example.]

> - One **red** apple
> - Two **red** apples

Thus your "adjective" *hidden layer* should be singular.

Answer (score 2):

I would opt for **hidden layer sizes**.

I'm guessing the label is for a table or graph and you're labeling a list of different sizes. Since you're showing multiple sizes, so you pluralise "size".

"Hidden layer" is simply a specifier; it specifies the things that have the sizes that you are showing.

@FumbleFingers makes a very good point in the comments: labeling on graphs and charts tend to use the singular for things like table headings or axis titles. In that case, **hidden layer size** would be a better option.

However, if the label is for the graph/table/figure as a *whole*, then pluralising "sizes" probably *is* appropriate. In which case, the preceding holds: pluralise "size" not "later".

Comment: I disagree. In the vast majority of cases, labels on graphs, charts, lists, etc. specify things like ***height, age, sex, location*** in the *singular* form, even if there are multiple such elements within the thing referenced.

Comment: Good point, @FumbleFingers; I've updated my answer.

Comment: Downvote duly reversed. But I'll leave the original comment, since you've referenced it in the answer text.

Comment: The label is for user input (text box), I've also edited the question to mention that.

Answer (score 1):

I would use one of

- hidden layer sizes (preferred usage)
- sizes of hidden layers
- hidden layers' sizes (colloquial usage)

I can't quite visualize the question, actually. You wrote that it is to be a label for an input text box. Why would a single input require a plural? I am trying hard to imagine by thinking about the following examples.

Is it like this

```
Hidden layer ID:   [         ]
Hidden layer size: [         ]
```

or,

```
Hidden layers' size comma-list: [7, 20, 11, 19]

Hidden layer sizes comma-list: [7, 20, 11, 19]

Hidden layer sizes: [7] [20] [11] [19]

Average hidden layer size: [14.25]

Max hidden layer size: [20]

Hidden layer size range: [7] [20]

Show hidden layer sizes: []YES []NO

Show size of hidden layers: []YES []NO
```

?

Comment: It's like Hidden layer sizes comma-list: [7, 20, 11, 19]'. Appreciate your detailed approach.